# Scala: How to avoid check instance and casting

Tags: scala

I found myself sometimes in the condition of running:

```
someCollection.filter(_.isInstanceOf[Foo]).asInstanceOf[List[Foo]]
```

just to check if the collection has the instances of `Foo` and casting the final filtered collection.

Is there a better way to do that (assuming I cannot change the current data structure)?

I tried with:

```
someCollection.map(case c: Foo => c)
```

but at runtime it returns `MatchingError` as of course it is looking for all the remaining cases (`case _ =>`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
someCollection.collect { case c: Foo => c }
```